# Horizontal Javascript menu error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small problem with my JavaScript menu.

When I choose an item it shows me always the last sub menu.

This is very simple for people who are professionals in Javascript :p

Here is the sample:

### CSS

```
ul#midnav {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid thin #c8c8c8;
    padding: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
}
ul#midnav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
ul#midnav li a {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
    padding: 5px 13px 0px 5px;
    background: url('../image/arrow-topdown-gray.png') 100% 9px no-repeat;
}
ul#midnav li ul {
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    background: none;
    display: none;
    /* --Hide by default--*/
    width: 960px;
    height:28px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: solid thin #eeeeed;
}
ul#midnav li ul a {
    background: url('../image/arrow-left-gray.png') 100% 9px no-repeat;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="mid-nav">
        <ul id="midnav">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 5.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 5.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#midnav li a').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(function () {
            $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: added the jquery tag because Javascript !== jQuery.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea jquery is javascript...

Comment: very good @Neal ... but javascript is not jQuery.

Comment: But jquery **is** javascript. so just having the javascript tag is perfectly fine.

Comment: no, @Neal, it is not. having both is perfectly sufficient, but having only Javascript tags (a) prevents people who are jQuery officianados from participating in the question, and (b) gives the insinuation that you actually believe them to be identical entities. jQuery is a library built on top of Javascript, but is not required to use Javascript, and the functions he is attempting to use will not work unless the jQuery library is included. You can continue to argue your point, just realize that it is considered wrong by anyone with knowledge of both jQuery and Javascript.

Comment: your html isn't well-formed (1 extra closing div).

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your `ready` handler refers to the wrong object:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('ul#midnav li a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var e=this;
            // must alias or 'this' will refer to
            // the last submenu slid into hiding
            // instead of the one to open

        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(
          function(){
            $(e).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(); // 'e' instaed of 'this'
        });

      });
    });
```